# is there any compiler putting virtual base table ptr inside virtual function table?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

As I don't know how to check the memory layout in gcc, below result is coming from mscv.

I'm thinking that if we insert the vbptr inside the virtual function table, then we might save 4 bytes for every object, but cost on dereference vfptr every time to get the vbptr.

did any compiler try this, or I have some mistakes?

```
class A
    {
public: int a;
    virtual void Foo() {}
};
class B :virtual public A
{
public:int b;
       virtual void Bar(){}
};
sizeof(B) = 20;

class B size(20):
-------+----------
 0      | {vfptr}
 4      | {vbptr}
 8      | b
-------+----------
-------+----------(virtual base A)
12      | {vfptr}
16      | a
-------+----------

B::$vbtable@:
-------+----------
 0      | -4
 1      | 8 (Bd(B+4)A)
-------+----------
```

Comment: There is only one vptr per object.  The table it points to contains not just the functions for the current class but its parents too.

Comment: While different compilers are free to do different things, I'd guess probably not.   You're optimising the layout for a particular case.   The implementation needs to support all sorts of inheritance patterns (multiple inheritance, some class being both a virtual and [multiple times] a non-virtual base of some derived class).  Your optimisation (might) be fine for your particular hierarchy, but would make it more challenging for more general cases.

Comment: When you're at the stage of optimizing bytes off your objects, you may want to consider alternative design that maybe doesn't use built-in polymorphism. There are often spare bits inside an object where you can pack extra state information (_e.g._ to combine as an object type, which you then lookup your own optimized function tables).

Comment: Virtual function table is shared among all instances of the specific class. While its own vbptr must be present in each subobject dealing with virtual inheritance.